# Dynamic configuration of the WSO2ESB inbound endpoints

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'd like to dynamically change some of the parameters of my inbound endpoint. More precisely, I have a RabbitMQ inbound endpoint, and I would like to dynamically specify server host name, port, queue name, etc. How can I do this?

BTW, if it cannot be done with the existing components that's fine. It would also be great/acceptable if I could for example create a custom mediator that would read these properties from the message context and then ***somehow*** modify the RabbitMQ inbound endpoint, just how?

Comment: What is the WSO2ESB version you are trying?

Comment: The version is 4.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Specifying inbound endpoint parameters as registry values.

Other than specifying parameter values inline, you can also specify parameter values as registry entries. The advantage of specifying a parameter value as a registry entry is that the same inbound endpoint configuration can be used in different environments simply by changing the registry entry value.

```
<inboundEndpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="file" sequence="request" onError="fault" protocol="file" suspend="false">
   <parameters>
      ...............
      <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI" key="conf:/repository/esb/esb-configurations/test"/>
      ...............
   </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

Refer [1] for detailed explanation.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Working+with+Inbound+Endpoints

Comment: Thanks, but I think this doesn't solve my problem completely, since as far as I can tell, the registry is populated either through management console, or perhaps via XML files. However I would like to change these parameters programatically. Namely, I'd like to acquire configuration via RMI or a REST call and store it, preferably during deployment. Is there a way to add/remove/update registry entries by implementing a custom mediator for example?