# WSO2 inbound endpoint using registry entry

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to set up an inbound endpoint in ESB 5.0.0. This works fine when setting a fixed value for the file uri. But i am not able to set this with a registry value.
In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37543686/7689554) question someone asked almost the same. 
The answer is about setting `<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI" key="conf:/repository/esb/esb-configurations/test"/>`, but it does not explain what type of registry entry you need to have for a file endpoint.

Can someone give me a full explanation on how to set up a inbound endpoint with a fileuri that is defined in the registry?

The xml of the inbound endpoint

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <inboundEndpoint name="Poller.Label.Print.NL"
     onError="FaultSequenceEmail" protocol="file" sequence="LabelPrint"
     suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
    <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
    <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.LockReleaseSameNode">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.AutoLockRelease">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">conf:/test</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///c:\tdemo\error</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveTimestampFormat">yyyyMMddHHmmss</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.DistributedLock">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.dd</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileProcessInterval">10</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///c:\demo\archive</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAttribute">lastmodifiedtimestamp</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAscending">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.CreateFolder">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.Build">false</parameter>
  </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

tested with the following xml, but did not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <localEntry xmlns="ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="test"> 
       file:///c:/demo/ 
 </localEntry>
```

Comment: share the xml config for testing

Comment: I have updated the question with the inbound endpoint xml

Answer (score 0):

The file store in conf:/test need to have this content:

```
file:///c:\demo\
```

Check this:
[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. I added the used xml to my question

Comment: in the test registry just put this content: 

file:///c:\demo\ 

 not the full xml content

Comment: It might be something obvious, but i don't have a clue on how to achive what you suggest. Could you define the steps on how to do that?

Comment: my answer was updated with an image of my own path, you put your path. check now.

Comment: AS i thought it is simple enough, i got it to work too now. Thnx. Does this mean i have to create an registry entry for the fileuri and for the moveafter process and the moveafterfailure or can i make a registry entry with an xml and retrieve the filepaths from there?

Comment: As I saw, you need to create an entry registry for each path (file uri, move after and move after failure)